# Can't enter in Manager App tomcat

Tags: server, tomcat

I try to enter in Manager App tomcat directory, but after I enter password, I have

> Your connection to this site is not private

In log `catalina.out` I can see this message:

```
08-Dec-2017 09:03:36.024 SEVERE [main] 
org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm.startInternal Exception 
looking up UserDatabase under key [UserDatabase]
javax.naming.NamingException: The processing instruction target 
matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:856)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm.startInternal
(UserDatabaseRealm.java:230)
    at 
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at 
org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.startInternal
(CombinedRealm.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.startInternal
(LockOutRealm.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start
(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal
(ContainerBase.java:926)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal
(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start
(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal
(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start
(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal
(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start
(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:670)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start
(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
```

In user configuration file `tomcat-user.xml`:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin-script"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui,manager-
status,manager-script,manager-jmx,admin-gui,admin-script"/>
```

Can anybody say me, what I did wrong?
Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, I was must to appoint tomcat user to tomcat folder.
To install tomcat on server I used [this](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-on-ubuntu-server-16-04/) link, and [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-and-delete-users-on-ubuntu-16-04) to manage users. Hope it will helps anybody!